# How can formula in another sheet automatically detect a new row in Excel?

Tags: excel, vba

So I have created a Microsoft Flow between MS forms and an excel workbook.

Every time a form is submitted, the responses are collected in a table in a single row (4 columns). Every time a new form is submitted, a new row is inserted at the bottom.

For example, my table has one row (Row 1). a new survey is submitted ->  row 2 is created using MS flow.

Now I have another worksheet in the workbook that has some formulas looking at the row 1 in the table. The row in this new worksheet full of formula is also in A. Now when a new survey is submitted, I can't find a way to automatically detect the new row b and insert a new row into 2.

Is there something, like a macro that can do this?

Thanks  in advance.

Comment: @Jeeped if the OP is using Flow, chances are that they'll never touch Excel for Desktop and VBA is certainly not an option in this cloud scenario.

Comment: Forms stores the replies in an Excel workbook. Out of the box. Your question implies that you may be using Flow to re-create the same data in another workbook. Is that correct? If so, why would you want to do that? Why duplicate the data entry collection?

Comment: Hi guys, I am pushing the data from the survey into an excel sheet. I don't think it's being duplicated?

Answer (score 2):

Some terminology: In an Excel spreadsheet, a row does not have a letter. Row "A" and row "B" is just wrong wording. Please use the correct terms. It should be row 1 and row 2, but since you are writing into an Excel table, row 1 will be the column titles (or table headers), so your first row of data returned by Forms will be in row 2.

An Excel survey or Forms reply is not ***created*** with Flow, the Forms reply is collected with the Forms engine and added to the Excel workbook. If you have another sheet in the workbook that wants to evaluate the original responses coming in through forms, you can use an Index function and pre-fill it for the expected number of replies.

You can use formulas to pull the last populated row from the original data table.

You can use Flow to do something if the workbook that stores the Forms data is modified, but as far as I know, Flow does not have any tools to look at the "last" entry made in a Forms survey.

You may want to check your expectations and spell out what you would like to achieve before focusing on tools that may or may not be able to deliver that outcome.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. My terminology is all over the place because I am still learning.What I was referring to is there a formula in excel that can look at the new row entry and calculate that into the second worksheet automatically?